# (discord.py) My bot's whois command which also displays the user's roles displays "@everyone" as "@@everyone" How do I fix this

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My bot has a whois (alias userinfo) command which displays when the user joined the server, their highest role, etc. For the most part, this command works fine. But, the bot displays the role "@everyone" as "@@everyone" it displays every other role just fine. Here is my code:

```
@client.command(aliases=["whois"])
async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:  # if member is no mentioned
        member = ctx.message.author  # set member as the author
    roles = [role for role in member.roles]
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.purple(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
                          title=f"User Info - {member}")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}")

    embed.add_field(name="ID:", value=member.id)
    embed.add_field(name="Display Name:", value=member.display_name)

    embed.add_field(name="Created Account On:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
    embed.add_field(name="Joined Server On:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))

    embed.add_field(name="Roles:", value="".join([role.mention for role in roles]))
    embed.add_field(name="Highest Role:", value=member.top_role.mention)
    print(member.top_role.mention)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

And here is what the bot outputs when I use the command:

[image: Bot output]

I don't want the bot to display "@everyone" as "@@everyone". How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that in your current implementation using role.mention() on your bot message will notify everyone with that role, every time. Consider printing out the role name only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to display `@@everyone` just don't get it from your roles list: `roles = [role for role in member.roles[1:]]`

From docs:

> roles
>
> A list of Role that the member belongs to. Note that the first element of this list is **always** the default ‘@everyone’ role.

If you want to display `@@everyone` as `@everyone` you need to change this name, because name of this role is `@everyone` and first `@` indicates that it member's role.

Example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def who(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    roles = [role.mention for role in member.roles[1:]]  # don't get @everyone
    roles.append('@everyone')  # set string @everyone instead of role
    await ctx.send(" ".join(roles))
```

Result:

[image: Result]

P.S. But I think better use `@@everyone` instead of `@everyone` or don't use it ever (because all users have this role). Or you can use this role when member don't have any roles from your guild.